# Trouble Shoot: Programmatically add accessoryview to UITableViewCell messed up

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've stucked to this problem for couple days, and I've debugged it many times and can't figure out what's going wrong. 
I have a UITableView that has three sections. I'd like to add buttons as accessoryView and UILabel as detailText to the second section.
It looked OK when View first loaded.
[image]

But after scroll it, it becomes [image]

After couple scrolls, it freezes (not crash).
Below is my code, any advise will be appreciated.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
        return self.status.count;
    }
    else if (section==1)
        return self.overrideCtrl.count;
    else
        return self.levelStatus.count;
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"section %@",indexPath);
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.status objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"Status %@",cell.textLabel.text);
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.overrideCtrl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:%02d",[[self.timeLeftArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]];//[[self.timeLeftArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
        cell.accessoryView=[self.checkButtonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"override %@",cell.textLabel.text);

    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.levelStatus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"level %@",cell.textLabel.text);

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is covered a lot on SO, it's because of cell reuse. You need to set the accessoryView to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone for your other sections, otherwise, a cell that was used for section one might be used in another section, and still have its accessory view.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It works. I tried to search for a solution, but nothing useful came out, probably because I used the wrong keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You only have 1 `CellIdentifier`. You should have a different one for each section.

Comment: My tableview is dynamic, can I set cell identifier for each section through code?